# Split files on the basis of grep matches

Tags: grep

How can I split a file into two files with one file containing the lines that match the pattern while the other containing the lines that do not match the pattern? I want to specify the patterns to match in another file. 
The lines are mutually exclusive i.e. the line belonging to one category cannot belong to the other one. 
I can do two `grep`s separately but I want to iterate the file only one time.

What I have been doing right now is:

```
grep -F -f regexp_file input_file>./positive_match
grep -F -f -v regexp_file input_file>./negative_match
```

Comment: awk might be better option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is part input, (to read the input file from the disk only once), and part processing, (to iterate through the file only once).

Since `grep` can only output to one stream, the iterate portion of the job can't be done with only one instance of `grep`.

The input portion of the job can be improved:

```
tee >(grep -F -f regexp_file    >./positive_match) < input_file | \
      grep -F -f regexp_file -v >./negative_match
```

By using `tee` and `bash`'s *Process Substitution*, the `input_file` only needs to be read from the disk once.  The [`pee` command](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) can do the same thing:

```
pee 'grep -F -f regexp_file    >./positive_match' \
    'grep -F -f regexp_file -v >./negative_match' < input_file
```